# Thinkpad Yoga TouchPad gestures stop working

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, touchpad, thinkpad

I am having a problem with my Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga in that it seems that the Touchpad has the tendency to stop recognizing multi-touch gestures like scrolling or zooming after the device has gone into standby and then resumed (closed the lid and opened it again a bit later). I am assuming that there is some service that does not restart properly or something.

To be more precise, the exact model number of my PC is 20CD001SZA and it is obviously running Windows 8.1 with the latest updates installed. I have though rolled back the Touchpad driver to the previous release because with the latest release this problem gets worse in the sense that the touchpad then has the tendency to stop working completely.

Any ideas what I can do?

EDIT:
PS. I cannot seem to find a download link to the drivers on Lenovo's site, I am merely making use their default updating software to update the touchpad drivers.

Comment: Touchpad gestures are handled by drivers.  If the drivers are buggy or do not fully support Windows 8.1 what you describe is likely to surface.

Comment: @Ramhound that is what I assume is happening but I am hoping that someone here knows of a trick to fix this or a link to a revision of the driver that worked better.